# Can I have a subclass for each class when multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, archetype

In D&D 5e, if for example, I chose a Wild Magic Sorcerer, and later on wanted to become a Wizard, would I get to choose another subclass for Wizard?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Rp_Master We'd rather leave answering the question for answers, rather than comments.

Answer (score 23):

### Yes, you get a subclass for each class

Gaining a subclass is one of your class features (gained somewhere between 1st and 3rd level, inclusively). When multiclassing, you gain all class features of both classes (with some exceptions around spell slots, Extra Attack, etc.; see the multiclassing rules on [proficiencies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Proficiencies) and [class features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#ClassFeatures) for details).

So when you take your second level of the wizard class, you gain the Arcane Tradition feature, which lets you choose a wizard subclass.

Keep in mind that [you cannot choose multiple subclasses for the same class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49758/can-a-5e-dd-character-acquire-multiple-archetypes-from-the-same-class).

Comment: You could, theoretically get 9 subclasses (assuming you meet the multiclassing requirements) with Cleric, Warlock, Sorcerer, Wizard, Druid, and any other 4.

Comment: I don't think this answer clarifies if you can take multiple subclasses from the same class.  Is clarification on this needed?

Comment: @Imaginary I think we already have that covered elsewhere: [Can a 5e D&D character acquire multiple archetypes from the same class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49758/52137). Unless there's some other misunderstanding I'm not perceiving.

Comment: @Imaginary: That's what I expected this question to be asking, based on the title, because I thought it was well-known and fairly obvious that you have a subclass for each of your separate classes.  But that does seem to be all that this is asking.  If this question comes up in search results for people looking for the trickier question you brought up, then yeah it is useful to have at least a link to the existing Q&A about that.

Comment: Another exception to gaining class features: armor and skill proficiencies don't fully transfer.