# Is it possible to switch archetypes?

Tags: dnd-5e, archetype, retraining

Is it possible to start the Eldritch Knight progression then switch to another archetype, say Battle Master archetype, later?

I'm thinking that I'd like to get a *Hammer of Thunderbolts*, but if I do it would be *really* nice to have the Eldritch Knight archetypes's **weapon bond** so that I can recall it easily instead of having to retrieve it every time I throw it far enough to stay out of the blast radius. (Throwing it at least 30′ would make it take more than a round for a typical dwarf to chase after it.) It looks like Eldritch Knight is the only way to get **weapon bond**, but I am not interested in any of the other Eldritch Knight abilities beyond that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as the rules are concerned, no.

> At 3rd level, you choose an archetype [...]

There are no rules or features that contradict this statement. You choose an archetype at 3rd level and it's yours for life.

Comment: Just wondering, couldn't another archetype be considered another class? Thus having a dual class Fighter - Fighter with two different archetype would offer the feat (at a rather high cost I guess... but he *only* needs to waste 3 levels).

Comment: @AlexisWilke We already have a question on that here: [Can you multiclass the same class twice for different class features?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46700/15469)

Comment: There are a few exceptions however, like the Oathbreaker Paladin for example.

Comment: "There are no rules or features that contradict this statement" There are if you're playing an Adventurer's League game.

Comment: @nick012000 DDAL games allow unlimited complete rebuilds until the character's first adventure at L5 - you can still only have one archetype at a time. The question is asking about cherry picking archetype features.