# Can an Intellect Devourer in its new body continue to gain levels? (D&D 5e)

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, character-levels, special-abilities

In D&D 5e, When an Intellect Devourer consumes the brain of a 3rd-level fighter, for instance, can it continue to gain fighter levels?

Or due to its monstrous nature, is it locked to that 3rd-level state?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Which RPG and edition are you asking about? (I'm guessing it's probably an edition of D&D or Pathfinder, but which one?)

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify if you are asking about 5e vs some other edition of DnD.

Comment: Thanks, I often forget in my own little world that not everyone is using the same edition as me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're asking about [Intellect Devourer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17163-intellect-devourer)s in **D&D 5e**, then when it uses its *Body Thief* ability it gains the ability to use all of the target's statistics with the exception of its Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. This includes the **abilities** of the 3rd-level fighter.

The Intellect Devourer is a Monster, however, not a player character. Generally Monsters don't have character classes unless the DM is using [the "Monsters with classes" rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#MonsterswithClasses) from the Dungeon Master's Workshop in the DMG.

At that point, **if** the DM wants to have the Monster begin to gain class levels it seems like it would be logical to assign future levels in light of the Monster already having abilities equivalent to a character having three fighter levels (i.e., on level up have the monster acquire the abilities of a 4th level fighter). This prevents the Monster from getting the benefits of a 1st-level fighter twice, something that [isn't available to PCs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/can-you-multiclass-the-same-class-twice-for-different-class-features).

Comment: Since the asker has not specified a game system, it might be good to indicate you are answering for [tag:dnd-5e]

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I did a bunch of assuming there.

Comment: Yeah I meant 5e, updated Q, but that was the answer I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! While I appreciate you accepting my answer, typically folks wait a day or so to not discourage other folks from answering. Someone else might have another perspective you might find valuable as well!